# How to use Python left outer join using FOR/LIST/DICTIONARY comprehensions (not SQL)?

Tags: python, left-join, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I have two tuples, details below:

```
t1 = [
['aa'],
['ff'],
['er']
]
```

```
t2 = [
['aa', 11,],
['er', 99,]
]
```

and I would like to get results like these below using python method similar to SQL's LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
res = [
['aa', 11,],
['ff',  0,],
['er', 99,]
]
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your attempt at a solution. Thank you.

Comment: I can't because I don't know how to resolve this using tuples not SQL tables

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
d2 = dict(t2)
res = [[k[0], d2.get(k[0], 0)] for k in t1]
```