# Left outer join with Elixir's for comprehension

Tags: elixir

I've been looking at what I can do with `Enum`, `Stream` and `for` comprehensions and I'm struggling to reproduce left outer join behavior. I can implement a left outer join function with `Enum.reduce` but if there is some way to do that with `for` I'd rather use that.

I know python supports it, I've seen it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099022/how-to-use-python-left-outer-join-using-for-list-dictionary-comprehensions-not) and [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/159974-sql-like-set-operations-with-list-comprehension-on/), and I suppose Elixir's comprehensions were inspired by python's. Can we do it in Elixir?

Suppose I have two lists that came from an external API or some json/xml file:

```
categories = [%{id: 1, name: "beverages"}, %{id: 2, name: "vegetables"}]
products = [%{name: "ice tea", category: 1}, %{name: "sake", category: 1}]
```

I want to left outer join them to get something like:

```
cat_product == [
  %{category: "beverages", product: "ice tea"},
  %{category: "beverages", product: "sake"},
  %{category: "vegetables", product: "(No product)"}
]
```

And something like:

```
cat_products == [
  %{name: "beverages", products: [list of products]}
  %{name: "vegetables", products: []}
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example cannot be elegantly written with a for loop on the outside, because there can be records in the left list that are joined to more than one record in the right list. A `for` comprehension will however produce at most one result per element in the original collection. In this case, it would be more suitable to use `Enum.flat_map`:

```
Enum.flat_map categories, fn(c) ->
  case Enum.filter(products, fn(p) -> p.category == c.id end) do
    [] ->
      [%{name: c.name, product: nil}]
    prods ->
      for p <- prods, do: %{name: c.name, product: p.name}
  end
end
```

Your second example can be easily implemented just with `for` comprehensions, since there is always exactly one element in the result set per element in the original collection. Instead of using `Enum.filter`, the filtering is done with the second parameter to the inner `for` comprehension which makes the code much cleaner.

```
for c <- categories do
  prod = for p <- products, p.category == c.id do
    p.name
  end
  %{name: c.name, products: prod}
end
```